# In The 100, where is the round skyscraper located?

Tags: the-100

I have found this theory crafters map of the area that the TV show “The 100” is set in.

[image: Fan-made map of site from "The 100" showing the drop ship 20 miles from Mount Weather to its west, with caves and bunker between, then 60 miles southeast to Washington passing Camp Jaha. The National Zoo, Lincoln Monument and Washington Monument are marked.]

Now I have tried searching for the skyscraper that seems to be seat of power in the show. The building is round and quite tall. I have searched Washington DC and Annapolis but that is about it. I can't find it.
Here is a picture of the building I'm talking about (sorry for not being able to find a better one)

[image: Red-haired woman in fatigues standing on a rock looking at the ruins of a skyscraper with a circular cross-section rising from and evergreen forest in fog]

EDIT

here is a bit better picture of the top of the building and the background.

[image: Close in shot of the top 15 or so storeys of the ruined circular skyscraper, which steps in slightly every 5 floors. A 5-storey tall roughly conical structure sits on the roof rising to a flat disk on top of which is a flame. The background is treed hills rising to low mountains in the distance.]

[image: A panoramic version of the previous image, zoomed back enough to see half a dozen more storeys of the tower and a smaller tower beside it. The wider view shows more hills and a line of mountains along the horizon.]

Comment: what is "theory crafters", out of interest?

Comment: The DC-Annapolis area doesn't have any large pine forests. The ground's not conducive to building skyscrapers, either.

Comment: I immediately thought of the US Bank Tower in LA with some artistic privileges taken.

Comment: As mentioned in a (self-deleted) answer, this link might be useful: http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Locations

Comment: I know it's been a while since you asked this question, but I may be able to help.To my knowledge, the tower from the show is not a real building and definitely a composite made up of parts, of real buildings and some made up stuff. I definitely see the US Bank Building in Los Angeles forming most of the height- with some changes. Also, the top is definitely from the Mather Building in Chicago.

Comment: @JoeL It also doesn't have mountains that tall anywhere nearby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**We don't know**

There's been no confirmation of where it is, or if it even exists in the real world. The nuclear war started [in the year 2052](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) so it could have been built after 2016.

The only clues as to the real world location are based on speculation [derived from traveling distance to Arkadia](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Polis), such as Baltimore or Annapolis.

Annapolis was originally the most popular fan theory due to the similarity in the names (consider that Ton DC comes from Washington DC). However Jason Rothberg [tweeted](https://twitter.com/jrothenbergtv/status/584441694990381056) that this isn't the reason for the name (and we now know the reason from the show). However it's not clear whether he is saying that it's not Annapolis or just that it doesn't take it's name from Annapolis.

Comment: Polis they call the Capitol. Polis we learn is Polaris from the escape pod of the 13th station. so it isn't Annapolis as fans have always speculated.
The only known "fixed" reference is Mt. Weather.  Tondc can still be Washington DC as the last 5 letters match 100%

Comment: @Cherubel yeah that's what I meant by "(and we now know the reason from the show)" referring to the name coming from Polaris. It could still be the location even if it's not the reason for the name. In relaity I don't think we will find out. Jason Rothberg doesn't seem overly keen on mapping every fictional location to a real world location. Probably because it would become complicated, and would limit freedom regarding changes and storylines later on.

Answer (score 4):

Los Angeles US Bank Building - doesn't match with the distance that they travel, but....

[image: A tall white tower with slight curves in the sides that step back to reveal a circular core for the top dozen or so storeys. It is set among a number of shorter, more boxy towers]

Answer (score 2):

The bombs went off in 2052. So it's possible, especially after reading thru post, that it was built after 2016. Especially if it is still standing. Must have been built to withstand earthquakes & bombs.  Only outside is damaged the inside looks intact.  So apparently in the writers eyes we will build a building like this in D.C. area over next 30 years. Is possible since we don't have an ARC built for space yet either. And is there really a MT Weather like this in the show? That's 7 stories deep? Anything is possible from now until 2052....But don't believe it's in Africa, GA nor CA. It's in the eastern US near DC since Lincoln still sits from the Lincoln memorial. Hey. It could be a New Trump tower! Since he's in DC now?!

Answer (score 0):

The Tower looks like it could be the remains of The Mandarin Oriental Hotel in Atlanta, Georgia.

[image: An octagonal white tower, approximately 40 storeys tall, surrounded by lower buildings and 3 shorter towers on a very flat landscape]

This is the building, looks like the Tower..I'm sure it could be any number of buildings, just my 2 cents...:-)

Comment: Agreed it looks similar, however, I think Atlanta, GA is a bit far way for how quickly people seem to get back and forth between Polis and other known locations like Mt Weather.  (Google Maps says it would be ~200h walking - over a week, and that's only travel time, not accounting for sleeping, hunting or anything else.)

Comment: looks similar to a point. the building in the show is round, the one in your picture not so much. also it is too far away to be the possible candidate. The building, if it exists in our time is somewhere in the upper right corner of the USA. ( Pennsylvania, New Jersy, Virginia, and the states that border with these )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of Marina buildings in Chicago

[image: Twin round grey concrete towers with scalloped balconies around the 40 residential floors, set above approximately 15 levels of parking garage.]

Comment: it is round so that matches. but there are 2 side by side, it sits on a river canal so that doesn't match either. it has balconies all over so that doesn't match either.

Answer (score 0):

Capella Tower, Minneapolis
But with some of it's square weight shed. Still quite a distance away, but with 12-13 clans there should be some distance between them.

Comment: please add a picture. the ones I found have a cylinder and a rectangle melded together. dunno if it is the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

It's a fictional building.. no such building exists within 100 miles of current wash dc.

Tondc =Washing"ton DC".. they may have tweeted that's not the case but I don't by it.. it's right there in D.C.
Polis=Ana"polis"
Arkadia was probably named for: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadia_Conference

The fire on top looks like an Olympic Games brazier .. maybe they were hosted there in 2032, 2040, or 2048

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to existing answers.

Comment: The Olympic Games do as a possible reason for the buildin

Comment: Arkadia was named after The Ark and Polis after Polaris, the 13th station.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[St. George's Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_George_Wharf_Tower), although it is in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the Capitol Records Tower but taller (maybe more futuristic)  I'm assuming they're in Washington DC because when Octavia was injured Lincoln left her near the Lincoln Memorial.

[image: A round white 12-storey building with overhanging sunshades on every floor]

And here is a picture found of the Lincoln memorial from the show.
[image: A dark-haired person wearing a navy backpack looks along a gap in the surrounding forest, possibly a stream bed, with a high bank on the right side, to a seated statue of Abraham Lincoln which alone remains of the Lincoln Memorial]

Comment: It looks nothing at all like the Capitol Records Tower. The tower is much, much shorter, squatter and doesn't have the "thingy" on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

Isrotel Tower Hotel, Tel Aviv, Israel

[image: isrotel tower hotel, Israel]

Seems a bit far away...

Answer (score -3):

Ponty Tower,
Johannesburg, South Africa

[image: A wide circular grey tower, approximately 40 storeys tall, with an orange-red advertising banner about 5 storeys tall on top]

Comment: The OP is asking where in the setting of the show the building exists. As the show takes place in the vicinity of present-day Washington DC, this doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the building in the show is this tower, as opposed to any number of similar looking towers found elsewhere in the world? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Rotunda,_Birmingham_July_2007.JPG / http://smg.photobucket.com/user/RafflesCity/media/TT0701.jpg.html

Comment: it is round. but it is hollow inside, to thick and too short to be the correct one. The building in the show is much slimmer and taller and has a covered top. This one doesn't. it is hollow in the middle.