# How large is the geographic range depicted in the setting of the TV series "The 100"?

Tags: the-100

By which I mean, how much (or how little...) distance is there between the different locations depicted in the TV show?

The locations depicted at different times in the show vary greatly: woodland, mountainside, lush meadows, arid desert, open water and urban remnants of destroyed cities/towns etc.. Season 3 introduces an "Ice Nation" which presumably indicates there is also a very cold, icy/snowy region within the auspices of the "Twelve Clans" of grounders. (NB, I have only seen the first 5 episodes of Season 3 so far).

Yet, aside from the occasional motorised car journey of unspecified length in more recent episodes (since all the establishment of Arkadia), travel mostly occurs by foot or by horseback, and accordingly there is little to no indication of the distances traversed being particularly large (events move at a fast pace and travel time appears to be a non-factor in the plot.).

This is somewhat strange, because the setting is meant to be post-apocalyptic North America (somewhere near the region of Washington DC). One would expect the world of the show to have a broad scope given the size of modern-day North America and the variety of climates depicted, and the improbable likelihood that there would be so much variance in what would be a relatively small area (and so many distinct groups of people living so close together). And yet the logistics of the show does not reflect this.

So, are the distances between the settings in the show intended to be particularly large, or is the lack of long and arduous travelling depicted or mentioned in the show just an omission by the writers/producers of the show?

Answer (score 1):

The last question asked about the 100 has a map, looks like the largest distance between any two places in the show is about 80 miles. Remember that even with a vehicle there is no road so they wouldn't be able to drive highway speed, could take them a few hours to drive 80 miles.

[In The 100, where is the round skyscraper located?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122351/in-the-100-tv-show-where-is-the-round-skyscraper-located)

Comment: how did I miss that? What is "theory crafters", presumably a fan site not anything official? Edit: I missed it because it's a new question and I had not checked since yesterday. Doh!