# Where are the locations Clarke has listed in 'Heavy Lies The Crown'?

Tags: real-location, the-100

In the episode titled, 'Heavy Lies the Crown' Clarke has a list of unknown locations that includes: Rendon, Doah, Reva, Rappahan, Mana, Drom, Woodstock, Rockburn, Xandria, Beda, Nadal, Bowie, Dalk, Aldo, and Nopar. Where are they located?

[image: Other Locations]

[image: Raven's Map]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears most of these are corruptions/abbreviations of current cities/locations in and around the Eastern seaboard such as Virginia and D.C. Others are likely new names that emerged. E.g. The most likely explanation of the TonDC placename is Washington D.C.  Other names would possibly be as listed below. The likelihood of these being correct is reinforced if one looks at the listing seeing that it starts with those in Virginia and ends with those in Maryland.  While there are a couple of names I could not identify, if my theory is correct, there should be place names in the respective states which correspond do the names I could not immediately identify.

In particular if one traces a line starting at Dundalk, MD and draws a line Southwest through Washington D.D. to the Shenandoah park/river area, one can see how the place names are in a rough scatter pattern around that line.

**VIRGINIA NAMES:**

Rendon      - Herndon, VA

Doah        - Shenandoah River Valley, VA

Reva        - Reva, VA

Rappahan    - Rappahannock River & Rappahannock County, VA

Mana        - Manassas, VA

Drom        - ??

Woodstock   - Woodstock (likely the VA or MD location, not the original NY.  But based on the theory above, likely VA given proximity to other VA cities.)

Rockburn    - Rockburn Farm, VA

Xandria     - Alexandria, VA

**MARYLAND NAMES**

Beda        - Bethesda, MD

Nadal       - Ananndale, MD?

Bowie       - Bowie, MD

Dalk        - Dundalk, MD

Aldo        - Waldorf, MD

Nopar       - North Potomac, MD?

Comment: Nadal = Annandale, perhaps?

Comment: @hobbs.  An excellent suggestion. I have updated with that as an option.

Comment: TonDC we know is Washington DC. What about the actual location of Polis which we know actually stands for Polaris, the name on the pod Becca came down in?

Comment: @Michael.  Nobody is sure on that one.  The following question discusses the issue with trying to locate the tower in Polis. So far, nothing has been confirmed.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122351/in-the-100-where-is-the-round-skyscraper-located/154214#154214

Comment: Yes, I saw that question as well. They seem to be trying to find the building. I just want to know the location.

Comment: @Michael. To a large extent I would think they would be one and the same.  I.e. if they find the building, they find the town. Conversely if we knew the town, it could be confirmed by seeing the existing tower in it.  Unless of course, the writers decide to go with the claim that even if the town of Polis is near some current location/city the tower does not exist yet. As the link suggests that might be a deliberate step as the series creator/writers may not want to tie themselves too closely to an existing city as it might constrain future story lines.

Comment: The reality is that it is all filmed in Vancouver, Canada: you are not going to find the building...